# When was the festival of the See of Peter in the 6th Century?

Tags: christianity, early-medieval, religious-history

I've been researching the decrees of the second Council of Tours (AD 567), specifically [Canon XXII](https://archive.org/details/historyofcouncil04hefeuoft/page/392):

> 22. Some still hold fast the old error, that they should honor the 1st of January. Others, on the festival of the See of Peter, present meat offerings to the dead, and partake of meats which have been offered to demons. Others reverence certain rocks, or trees, or fountains, etc. The priests should root out these heathenish superstitions. (1)

I understand the 1st of January to have been when Consuls entered office and citizens would renew vows, make offerings to chief deities such as Jupiter and Juno, and take auspice.

But when was the festival of the See of Peter in the 6th Century?

Does it correspond to the Feast of Saints Peter and Paul?

Personally, I'm not familiar with the calendrical history and the changes the calendar went through.

---

(1) A History Of The Councils Of The Church Volumes 1 to 5 by Charles Joseph Hefele D.D. Chapter I, The synods until the end of the sixth century.

Comment: Please consult the [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chair_of_Saint_Peter#Feast_of_the_Chair_of_Saint_Peter) and [*Catholic Encyclopedia*](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03551e.htm) articles on this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In his [History of the Councils of the Church, Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/historyofcouncil03hefeuoft/page/266), Charles Hefele records that:

> ...  the Latin Emperor Valentinian III came with his wife Eudoxia (a daughter of Theodosius II.), and his mother Galla Placidia (aunt of Theodosius), to Rome, in order to pay his devotions there on the Festival of the holy Apostle Peter (at the ***Festival of the See of Peter, S. Peter’s Day, February 22, 450***)

- p266 (my emphasis)

As the [Wikipedia page on St Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter#Feast_days) notes,

> In the Roman Rite, the feast of the Chair of Saint Peter is celebrated on 22 February

This is confirmed on the [website of the Liturgy Office](http://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Calendar/Extraordinary/February.shtml) of The Catholic Church in England and Wales.

So it would appear that the date of the festival has remained unchanged on 22 February since at least the fifth century.

Comment: I think there is confusion between the “see of Peter” (sedes Petri), meaning the city of Rome and (in a narrower sense) the papal court, and the “chair of Peter” (cathedra Petri), the physical chair built into the high altar in the Basilica of St Peter. The latter has only been in Rome since the 9th century, so the Council of Tours could not have referred to this.

Comment: @fdb The 'chair' in the _feast of the Chair of Saint Peter_ on February 22 refers to the [See of Antioch.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarch_of_Antioch) (the festival for the See of Peter at Rome was on 18 January). See also [Catholic Culture.org](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/calendar/day.cfm?date=2018-02-22)

Comment: So was the physical cathedra of Peter kept in Antioch before being removed to Rome?

Comment: Is this date given in the Julian Calendar -- not matching today's feast day?

Comment: @fdb My understanding is that there were 2 physical cathedrae venerated by the early church,  I couldn't say whether either were ever in Antioch, and neither survive today. Apparently, the festival on 22 February was [originally the most important](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03551e.htm) of the two which, I suppose, is why Dr Hefele refers to that date for the Festival of the See of Peter.

Comment: @AaronBrick Why would the change in calendar change the feast days?  After all, Christmas Day is still on 25 December.

Comment: In that case Hefele's translation ("See of Peter") is wrong.

Comment: @fdb That is possible. It is also possible that the nomenclature has changed since the Great Schism.  However, note that both the translation in the question and that in my answer are by Dr Hefele, so one might at least hope they are consistent!  I guess that we'd need to locate a list of the decrees of the 2nd Council of Tours in the original Latin to be sure though.

Comment: I found it: …in festivitate cathedrae domni (sic) Petri apostoli…

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PI9EAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA380&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false col. 365

Comment: @fdb So the _Festival of the See of Peter_ is a (very) loose translation! (I'll have to take your word for the Google text though. It won't zoom very well on my phone, and that font is playing merry Hell with my eyes!)

Comment: I'm pretty confident the 22nd of February is correct seeing as it's the same date as the Roman festival of [Caristia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caristia), explaining the comment on offerings to the dead

Comment: @sempaiscuba I had imagined the feast days being translated for the new calendar, and I think you are saying that they were not. Thanks!

Comment: @sempaiscuba Not a few Orthodox folks are still adding 13 days to keep using a Julian liturgical calendar.

Answer (score 2):

**When was the festival of the See of Peter in the 6th Century?**

It would seem that the festival in question would be the **Feast of the Chair of St. Peter**. But the date of this feast was **January 18** and not February 22, as noted in [Sempaiscuba's answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/49560/19246).

In the modern liturgy of the Roman Rite, the Feast of the Chair of St. Peter is the 22nd of February. But prior to 1969, this feast was in fact on January the 18th. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter#Feast_days) backs this up.

> In the Roman Rite, the feast of the Chair of Saint Peter is celebrated on 22 February.
>
> Before Pope John XXIII's revision in 1960, the Roman Calendar also included on 18 January another feast of the Chair of Saint Peter (denominated the Chair of Saint Peter in Rome, while the February feast was then called that of the Chair of Saint Peter at Antioch).

The Catholic Encyclopedia is still clearer:

> From the earliest times the Church at Rome celebrated on 18 January the memory of the day when the Apostle held his first service with the faithful of the Eternal City. According to Duchesne and de Rossi, the "Martyrologium Hieronymianum" (Weissenburg manuscript) reads as follows: "XV KL. FEBO. Dedicatio cathedræ sci petri apostoli qua primo Rome petrus apostolus sedit" (fifteenth day before the calends of February, the dedication of the Chair of St. Peter the Apostle in which Peter the Apostle first sat at Rome). The Epternach manuscript (Codex Epternacensis) of the same work, says briefly: "cath. petri in roma" (the Chair of Peter in Rome).
>
> **In its present (ninth-century) form the "Martyrologium Hieronymianum" gives a second feast of the Chair of St. Peter for 22 February**, but all the manuscripts assign it to Antioch, not to Rome. Thus the oldest manuscript, that of Berne, says: "VIII kal. mar. cathedræ sci petri apostoli qua sedit apud antiochiam". The Weissenburg manuscript says: "Natl [natale] sci petri apostoli cathedræ qua sedit apud antiocia." However, the words qua sedit apud antiochiam are seen at once to be a later addition. Both feasts are Roman; indeed, that of 22 February was originally the more important. This is clear from the Calendar of Philocalus drawn up in the year 354, and going back to the year 311; it makes no mention of the January feast but speaks thus of 22 February: "VIII Kl. Martias: natale Petri de cathedra" (eighth day before the Calends of March, the birthday [i.e. feast] of the Chair of Peter). **It was not until after the insertion of Antioch in the copies of the "Martyrologium Hieronymianum" that the feast of February gave way in importance to that of January**. The Roman Church, therefore, at an early date celebrated a first and a second assumption of the episcopal office in Rome by St. Peter. - [Chair of Peter](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03551e.htm)

The Church of [St. Peter of Antakya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Saint_Peter) (Antioch) is locally believed to be the Church founded by the apostle St. Peter. This is the first see founded by this Prince of Apostles. With the reform of the liturgical calendar, the feast of the Chair of St. Peter at Rome is celebrated on February 22.  The feast of the Chair of St. Peter at Antioch was suppressed.  Notwithstanding this fact, the local church at Antioch nowadays celebrates its' own particular Feast of the Chair of St. Peter, on February 21st.

If the second feast (February 22) only took on importance in the ninth century, then the Festival of the See of Peter in the 6th Century would have been on January 18 and not as [Charles Hefele](https://archive.org/details/historyofcouncil03hefeuoft/page/266) holds in his ***History of the Councils of the Church, Volume 3***.

[image: Facade of the Church of St Peter, originally built ca. 1100 by Crusaders and rebuilt in the 19th century]

Facade of the Church of St Peter, originally built ca. 1100 by Crusaders and rebuilt in the 19th century